# MV-Whatever Framework for iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

Are there any MVC/MVVM frameworks for iOS?  I understand that Cocoa uses (a form of) MVC, but I want something more defined, like `AngularJS` or `Caliburn Micro`.  Google doesn't seem to be helping me.  Maybe the consensus is that the base API is powerful enough, and its just a matter of becoming proficient?

(*To be clear, I'm not interested in projects like SSToolkit and other UI focused projects*)

Comment: Are you talking native app or compiled web app, like with PhoneGap?

Comment: I'm interested in native apps

Comment: AngularJS is a client-side javascript framework. It won't work inside of iOS.

Comment: I was hoping for something _similar_ to AngularJS or Caliburn (C#) in the iOS world -- an opinionated, convention over configuration application framework.

Comment: I encourage you to read Apple's "Cocoa Design Patterns". That will describe to you how Cocoa uses MVC. The pattern is used throughout Cocoa. Also do a search for MVC against developer.apple.com for further good information.